# For the SARIMA model, how can I plot diagnostics if I get 'int' object is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, arima

I am trying to plot diagnostics using results.plot_diagnostics(). However, I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Please see below:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: `print(self.model.endog_names)` before the line throwing the error.

Comment: NameError: name 'self' is not defined